# Why is my toString() class being automatically Overriden?

Tags: java, overriding

I am using Eclipse Build id: 20120614-1722.

I have an object class called "TOY1" and a function toString() within it. I previously know that when I call the

```
System.out.println(TOY1);
```

It should return the address. However, and for some reason it is returning the toString() declared for my object without me specifying the @Override notation.

Is it safe to keep it that way? Or is this a new feature implemented in the specific build I have.

Thanks

**EDIT**

As asked this is part of my code:

```
public class TOY1 {

//irrelevant declarations

public String toString() {
String data;
data="Manufacturer=";
data+=manufact;
data+="DOP:";
data+=date_of_production;
return data;
}
}
```

When declaring TOY1_instance of TOY1 and then printing out using the `System.out.printIn(TOY1_instance)`

I am getting the actual data as opposed to some junk address.

My question is where did I override it no warning was shown and no extension overrides this class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.out.println(obj);` is calling `obj.toString()` internally. It happens that the default implementation of `toString()`, if you don't override it, returns some address-like value.

You can omit `@Override` annotation, but it's *safer* to use it. It becomes especially useful when you *think* you are overriding while you aren't because of tiny difference in signature. E.g.:

```
@Override
public String tostring() //...
```

won't compile. Even more common mistake is wrong `equals()`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(TOY1 obj) //...
```

Do you see why? Without `@Override` it's very easy to miss such a tremendous bug.

Comment: "It happens that the default implementation of toString() if you don't override it, returns some address-like value." That is true and I was expecting to see an address-like value because I didn't override the toString() function. However, the output I received was the correct output. Any specific reason?

Comment: @Syntax_Error: apparently you *did* override it. `@Override` annotation is irrelevant, it's just for documenting and some static analysis. Maybe some class you extend overrides it instead?

Comment: @Syntax_Error If you have (question suggest so) function named `toString` that is `public` and returns `String`, you did override it. Annotation is just optional. Code of method and its signature is that what matters.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I think what dantuch mentioned might be my case. I attached my code above and I dont extend any class, but toString is public.

Comment: @Syntax_Error: once again, you **are** overriding `toString()`. The `@Override` annotation was added in Java 5 and even if you don't annotate overriding method with it, it's still overriding. It's only there to *document* and fail compilation if you don't actually override anything (see my examples). But ot's perfectly fine to override a method without using this annotation. There are tons of pre-5.0 methods without this annotation.

Answer (score 2):

`@Override` annotation is just optional,

code works the same with and without it.

But it's a matter of good taste, to use it. It clearly shows what's going on - that you redefine method from super-class or implement method from interface.

And as Tamasz mentioned - it's impossible to annotate with @Override method that actually isn't overriding anything. So it can save you sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

It would always run the closest toString() instance method even if @Override is not specified. To be on the safer side, or to compile quickly and effeciently, you should include @Override at the top

Answer (score 0):

`@Override` annotation is just for compilers, and JVM does not care about it.

See definition of `Override` annotation here:

```
@Target(value=METHOD)
@Retention(value=SOURCE)
public @interface Override
```

As you can see in the declaration, it is only retained in the source and not in the class file.

Answer (score 0):

OK let me get it clear. So, your over-ridden function is still called but the issue is why is it called even when @override is not used? If that is the case, then this annotation is simply for the compiler to check whether you have actually overriden the function or not. It should not affect the logic of program as such. Also, please post code if you want specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, System.out.println() can deal with several types of parameters, and one of them is reference to a String.

[Please refer this URL](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap27/ch27_10.html)